# like and regexp returning results outside of specified conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, operators, sql-like

I am trying to return results on specimen collectors from a MySQL database for a field when it contains 'with', 'and', ';' or '&' in order for these to data to be cleaned.

I have tried the following two queries in MySQL:

```
SELECT sp.barcode, sp.gard_collector
    FROM specimens sp
    WHERE  barcode is not null and 
   (sp.gard_collector regexp  '&+'
    or sp.gard_collector regexp 'and+'
    or sp.gard_collector regexp 'with+'
    or sp.gard_collector regexp ';+')
    ;

SELECT sp.barcode, sp.gard_collector
    FROM specimens sp
    WHERE  barcode is not null and 
   (sp.gard_collector like '%#&%' escape '#'
    or sp.gard_collector like '%and%' 
    or sp.gard_collector like '%with%'
    or sp.gard_collector like '%#;%' escape '#')
    ;
```

**I would expect to get:**

Smith, John & Bloggs, Joe

Smith, John; Bloggs, Joe

Smith, John with Bloggs, Joe

Smith, John and Bloggs, Joe

**However I am also getting:**

Smith, John
Bloggs, Joe

Is it something to do with using OR?

Comment: `+` means "1 or more occurences of previous char or group". Not previous word.

Comment: But why have the '+'?

Answer (score 2):

> specimen collectors from a MySQL database for a field when it contains 'with', 'and', ';' or '&'

I would expect logic like this:

```
where sp.gard_collector regexp 'with|and|;|[&]'
```

Comment: This still causes the same issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I've realised a very obvious mistake! I needed to have '% and %' not '%and%' similarly '% with %' instead of 'with' as it's returning surnames containing 'and' and 'with' rather than collector groups i.e.

Unwanted results:

Sutherl**and**, Bob

**With**erington, Sam

in addition to:

collector1 **and** collector2

collector1 **with** collector2

Comment: But for the additional output you got it makes no difference...

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.